# How to use Google sign-on across multiple platforms with Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My only solution so far is to use oauth with something like this:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/web-api-kit-oauth-token-interceptor-extension-40572

Are there any better solutions for this that will work across Windows, UWP, Linux, iOS, Android build targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the asset creator you mention in your post.  OAuth flow really depends on the API you are using.  Some allow for the key and secret to be input with no further data exchange.  However, most require a redirect to be present for an authentication code and access token exchange.  Take a look at different flows here https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/.  Also, a decent API will expire a token after a number of hours and hopefully provide a refresh token so that user consent is no longer necessary. You will need to handle the failed requests when submitting with an expired token so you don't break the user experience.  Also, our asset works across the platforms you mentioned.  It leverages Unity's UnityWebRequest.